# sharedApplication is not available

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Getting this error while running the app in xCode. App is using an older version of react native 0.64. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solutions

1. The error "'sharedApplication' is unavailable" can be resolved, according the instructions posted on the Apple Developer Forums, by reinstalling cocoapods and all pods.
2. Require Only App-Extension-Safe API can also be solved by setting it to "NO" in the target's build options.
3. Kindly insert these lines into your podfile and then reinstall each pod.

   ```
   use_flipper!()

   post_install do |installer|
   react_native_post_install(installer)

   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
         config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
       end
     end
    end
   end
   ```